# Delete client info using selectbox php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

Alright here's what am trying to do.

I have a table which returns the list of information aside from the name of each 97 clients per row. Now am planning to do a delete section in one of the pages tab.

Here's how I call the values from the database to display it on the table:

```
<span class="text"><?php echo $fname; ?></span>
<span class="text"><?php echo $lname; ?></span>
<span class="text"><?php echo $bday; ?></span>
```

I placed it under an array. So each time a new addition has been placed, it will automatically be displayed too.

Now getting back to the main topic. As for the delete section, here's what am trying to do:
Create a selectbox where it displays the Name of the client but the values fetched must be the ID.

So I interpreted the logic in this format:

```
<select>
<option value="<?php $id ?>"><?php $fname." ".$lname ?>
<option value="<?php $id ?>"><?php $bday ?>
</select>
```

What am trying to achieve here is once the user selects the name of the client he/she intends to delete, the system instead will get the value ID of the selected name then its details would be displayed on a textfields designated for each of the rows. Then once the button for delete (underneath these textfields) would prompt the question "Are you sure you want to delete  from the record?"
If the user clicks yes, then that selected name with that ID would be deleted from the DB.

That for me is quite tricky, since I didn't know if the way I call the $id on the option attribute for selectbox was even right? I just want to make it a referrence for the delete function like this:

```
$selectedID=$_POST['ID'];

sql="delete from clients where id='$selectedID' "
```

This should be the output:
(Note: I intend not to display the names of the clients for privacy purposes. So instead I wrote "List of Clients Name" supposing that it was all the clients name being displayed.)

[image: Output]

Once a name was selected, the textboxes below would be filled with the other information associated on the selected name. Like for example, that persons birthday, age... etc.
Then it would be deleted once the delete button was pressed
(sorry if the button is not included in the cropped image.)

Anyone who once had to deal with this or has an idea on how to achieve this? Need your help.

Figure 1:

```
<?php
       $name= mysql_query("select * from clients");

       echo '<select name="clients" id="clients" class="textfield1">';
       while($res= mysql_fetch_assoc($name))
                {

                //declaration of variables  

                echo '<option value="'.$cid.'">';
                echo $cname;
                echo'</option>';
                }
                        echo'</select>';
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for the php method, create a page

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $clients = mysql_query("select * from clients");
?>
<form method="post" action="<!--this same page-->">
    <select name="clients">
        <?php
            while($c = mysql_fetch_array($clients)) { ?>
                <select value="<?php echo $c['id']; ?>"><?php echo $c['name']; ?></select>
            <?php}
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Find">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['clients'])) {
    $id = $_POST['clients'];
    $client = mysql_query("select * from clients where id = ".$id);
    $client_data = mysql_fetch_array($client);
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="<!--this same page-->">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $client_data['name']; //the name of the client ?>">
        <!-- and so on with other inputs-->
        <input type="hidden" name="eliminate" value="<?php $id; ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Eliminate">
    </form>
    <?php
}
if(isset($_POST['eliminate'])) {
    $id = $_POST['eliminate'];
    //query to eliminate that client
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The first select box will always be there, so when you want to change a client, you just must select it and press the button.

Then it will trigger the first `if(isset($_POST['clients']))` where there creates a `form` with inputs with the values from the client. If you click the submit button, it will trigger the other `if(isset($_POST['eliminate']))`, that will contain the ID from the client and then eliminate it from the db.

Comment: I would love to try that. But am not that familiar with ajax. I don't even know where to start. :(

Comment: Do you know at least a bit of jQuery? Because if not you may can reach what you want to achive without javascript, but will require at page reload using php.

If the first answer is yes, this Ajax is going to be simple:

$("select").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val(); // the id from the option on the selectbox
    $("#name").load("get_info.php?id="+id+"&name");
    //This makes that what you echo in get_info.php will be displayed on this id (in this case, a textbox with id="name")
});

On get_info.php you can do a query to db, and depending on $_GET echo a value or another

Comment: If it's a negative answer to the first question, you can do a select box with a button to reach the info of the client and that button can make you go to the same page. Then, using if(isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != 0) make a query to the db and fill all the values with the information of the client, making a form that when is submited then eliminate that client

Comment: I think I'll try the option 2. :)

I've created a select box and here's my code for that

See Figure 1 at the post above.

Comment: Ok, i see. Then, in that case, make a page with a form that shows in a drop-down box all your clients with their ID as value.

Then, once you have submited it (in the same page), do a `if(isset($_POST['clients'])) {}` and inside there, include the query to db and fill all the inputs you want to show in a form a part from the first one. So when they click that button you can call the same page with an `if` statement to eliminate that ID, or another page to make it. I'll try to post the answer now.

Gonna edit the first one.

Comment: Can I use the previous selectbox? the one I stated above.

Comment: of course, remember to add a `form` tag sorrouding the select box and adding a submit button. I updated a bit the answer, think it more comprehensive now.

Comment: thanks but... only the delete had worked yet the textfields remain empty. :/

Comment: So, at least it enters the if() statement when you want to see a client? If it's, print the query to see if there's something wrong.

Comment: it didn't show any error, however, its as if the supposed value of each of the textfields couldn't be displayed.
 
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $client_data['name'];?>">

does it have something to do with how I declare the name of the inputs to reflect that of the names of the columns? for example the <input name="name"> is similar with the name column of the table then I declared it also as name in php.

But when I tried changing it still doesn't show.